# How to setup TFS 2013 to build either with Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, compilation, visual-studio-2017

We have TFS 2013 on one server and have Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 together on another server.  In the past, we built all of our applications with VS2013 but now some applications have been upgraded so we would like those to be built with VS2017.

How can I modify the build definition / template in TFS 2013 to build either with VS2013 or VS2017?  We have tried changing some of the MSBuild's arguments but no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: try to change the toolversion to point the vs 2013 E.g, `msbuild someproj.proj /tv:12.0 /p:Configuration=Debug` See hoe the [toolversion works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2015), and it's [order or precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/overriding-toolsversion-settings?view=vs-2015#order-of-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create the new build definition for VS 2017. Try next steps:

1. Install ms build for VS 2017 ([Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017))
2. Copy existing XAML process for your build through copy on version control or through creation of a new build definition [Copying build process template or reuse exsisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587309/copying-build-process-template-or-reuse-exsisting)
3. Update XAML process template to use the new ms build path (%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin). Example you may find here: [How does Team Foundation Build choose which version of Visual Studio to build with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613114/how-does-team-foundation-build-choose-which-version-of-visual-studio-to-build-wi)